# How to select the userful information in big file in short time with bash

Tags: awk

In my project, I have a file.

The file size is 655MB, and it has 737623 rows.

I selected some content of this file is like:

```
Job <831463>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 31 09:22:57: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <short>, CWD </scr
Wed Jul 31 09:23:47: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r09n12>, Allocated 40
Job <831953>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 31 09:37:28: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <medium>, CWD </sc
Wed Jul 31 11:47:05: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r05n42>, Allocated 40
Job <831954>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 31 09:37:28: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <medium>, CWD </sc
Wed Jul 31 09:47:05: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r12n45>, Allocated 40
Job <831955>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 30 09:37:29: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <medium>, CWD </sc
Wed Jul 31 09:47:07: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r03n10>, Allocated 40
Job <832272>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 31 09:48:12: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <short>, CWD </scr
Wed Jul 31 09:48:14: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r09n12>, Allocated 40
Job <823777>, Job Name <3rd>, User <mse-jiangf>, Project <default>, Mail <ritaq
Wed Jul 31 09:55:14: Submitted from host <login04>, to Queue <medium>, CWD <$HO
Thu Aug  1 12:57:12: Dispatched 20 Task(s) on Host(s) <20*r03n09>, Allocated 20
```

I need to count the time between Submitted and Dispatched.

For example, the job 831463:

```
Jul 31 09:23:47 - Jul 31 09:22:57
```

the result is 50 seconds.

But it will take more than one hour with for or while to this file .

Now I　want to exclude the job which Dispatched time minus Submitted time is less than one hour.

I want to select the result:

```
Job <831953>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 31 09:37:28: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <medium>, CWD </sc
Wed Jul 31 11:47:05: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r05n42>, Allocated 40
Job <823777>, Job Name <3rd>, User <mse-jiangf>, Project <default>, Mail <ritaq
Wed Jul 31 09:55:14: Submitted from host <login04>, to Queue <medium>, CWD <$HO
Thu Aug  1 12:57:12: Dispatched 20 Task(s) on Host(s) <20*r03n09>, Allocated 20
```

More than 95% of this jobs, is happened at the same hour.
In other words, Submitted time and Dispatched time is the same hour in this file 95% .

For example of job 831463:

Wed Jul 31 09:22:57: Submitted
   Wed Jul 31 09:23:47: Dispatched

are the same :  Wed Jul 31 09

So is there any way to select  5% of the job information  in short time?

My code is :

```
cat simplifyInf.txt | grep ^Job  | awk -F '[<>]' '{print $2}' > jobId.txt

for i in $(cat jobId.txt)
do
   grep -A 2 $i simplifyInf.txt | sort | uniq > tmpInfo
   subTime=`grep Submitted tmpInfo | awk  '{print $2" "$3" "$4}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1":"$2":"$3}'`
   disTime=`grep Dispatched tmpInfo | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1":"$2":"$3}'`

  subT=`date -d "$subTime" +%s`
  disT=`date -d "$disTime" +%s`
  resultT=`expr $disT - $subT`

  if [ "$resultT" -gt "3600" ]
  then
   cat tmpInfo >> result.txt
  fi
done
```

Comment: @Cyrus, see my update

Comment: Any time your are calling a utility like `awk` within a loop alarm bells should start going off in your head...(much less calling `grep 3-times, sort, uniq` and `awk 4-times` and `4-pipes`) For every utility, and pipe, called within a loop you spawn a separate subshell -- killing efficiency. A single call to `awk` will do it, and the entire script will likely complete within 10 sec.

Comment: This is some I would have logged to Splunk  (Splunk is free to use for up to 500MB/day).  You can then get all sorts of information and graphs from your data.

Comment: please post your example files without lines being wrapped

Answer (score 1):

With the limits knowing you have only posted partial lines from your data files (which so long as the fields are comma-separated should suffice), you can use `awk` alone to handle your problem.

**with the caveat** that since there is no **year** information provided in your file, in order to create a *datespec* from your date/time info, you must **assume** the current year (which will be a problem if the log submit and dispatch spans the change of year -- handling that case is left to you).

Your file has 3-repeating entries, e.g.:

```
Job <831953>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 31 09:37:28: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <medium>, CWD </sc
Wed Jul 31 11:47:05: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r05n42>, Allocated 40
```

The basic approach is to store each of the 3 lines as you convert the date/time information into a *datespec* (in `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS` format -- which is why the year is important) and then create a *timestamp* (in seconds since epoch) so you can subtract the submit from dispatch timespecs to determine if the difference is greater than or equal to `3600` seconds. If it is, you output the 3 lines you have stored, zero the variables, and repeat until you run out of lines.

The only *tedious* (not difficult) parts are that you must convert the abbreviated months (e.g. `"Jan, Feb, ..."`) into the numeric month (e.g. `1, 2, ... 12`), and then you must rearrange the date/time information and add the year to provide `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS` to `mktime` to create a timestamp from the log entries.

**note:** `mktime` is a GNU awk extension (though most other awks provide it as well), see [GNU awk - 9.1.5 Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions)

Writing a couple of short functions to convert the month abbreviations and log date/time into timespecs makes things less repetitive. For the month conversion you can do something similar to:

```
awk -F, -v y=$(date '+%Y') '
    # get current year above (no year info in data file)
    # function converts, e.g. "Jan" to 1, "Feb" to 2, ...
    function month (m) {
        switch (m) {
            case "Jan":
                return 1; break;
            case "Feb":
                return 2; break;
            case "Mar":
                return 3; break;
            case "Apr":
                return 4; break;
            case "May":
                return 5; break;
            case "Jun":
                return 6; break;
            case "Jul":
                return 7; break;
            case "Aug":
                return 8; break;
            case "Sep":
                return 9; break;
            case "Oct":
                return 10; break;
            case "Nov":
                return 11; break;
            case "Dec":
                return 12; break;
            case "?":
                return 0; break;
        }
    }
    ...
```

To create a timestamp from the date/time information, you take the start of each submit and dispatch line, e.g. `Wed Jul 31 11:47:05` (using `sub` and `gsub` to remove the rest of the field and replace the `':'` with `' '`) Then using `split` to split the parts into an array that you can add the year before and concatenate into `"YYYY MM DD HH MM SS"` format to create the timestamp with `mktime` you can do:

```
    # function converts datespec (from submit/dispatch time) to timestamp
    # (e.g. "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS" to seconds since epoch)
    function mktmstamp (str) {
        sub(/:[^:]*$/,"",str)   # remove from final : to end
        gsub(/:/," ",str)       # replace : in H:M:S with space
        gsub(/[ ]0/," ",str)    # remove any leading zeros from H M S
        split (str, a, " ")     # split m d H M S into array
        # return timestamp created from datespec
        return mktime(y " " month(a[2]) " " a[3] " " a[4] " " a[5] " " a[6])
    }
```

The rest of the script holding the logic is straight-forward. You just handle the `Jobs..` line, then check if your submit timestamp is set (if it is, make the comparison and output if >= 1 hour) and last (in backwards order to make the fill logic work) you handle the submit line last, e.g.

```
    # handle Job line, store line, zero variables
    /^Job/ {jobln=$0; tmsub=0; tmdis=0; next}
    # handle dispatched line, store, get dispatch timestamp, output all >= 1 hr
    tmsub != 0 {
        disln=$0
        tmdis=mktmstamp($1)
        if (tmdis-tmsub >= 3600)
            printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", jobln, subln, disln
    }
    # handle submit line, store line, get submit timestamp
    tmsub == 0 { subln=$0; tmsub=mktmstamp($1) }
```

That's pretty much it. I stored your input in a file named `jobs` (change to whatever your log file name is). You can then copy/middle-mouse-paste the following into a terminal and it should handle your file in less than a minute (maybe well less than a minute), e.g.

```
awk -F, -v y=$(date '+%Y') '
    # get current year above (no year info in data file)
    # function converts, e.g. "Jan" to 1, "Feb" to 2, ...
    function month (m) {
        switch (m) {
            case "Jan":
                return 1; break;
            case "Feb":
                return 2; break;
            case "Mar":
                return 3; break;
            case "Apr":
                return 4; break;
            case "May":
                return 5; break;
            case "Jun":
                return 6; break;
            case "Jul":
                return 7; break;
            case "Aug":
                return 8; break;
            case "Sep":
                return 9; break;
            case "Oct":
                return 10; break;
            case "Nov":
                return 11; break;
            case "Dec":
                return 12; break;
            case "?":
                return 0; break;
        }
    }
    # function converts datespec (from submit/dispatch time) to timestamp
    # (e.g. "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS" to seconds since epoch)
    function mktmstamp (str) {
        sub(/:[^:]*$/,"",str)   # remove from final : to end
        gsub(/:/," ",str)       # replace : in H:M:S with space
        gsub(/[ ]0/," ",str)    # remove any leading zeros from H M S
        split (str, a, " ")     # split m d H M S into array
        # return timestamp created from datespec
        return mktime(y " " month(a[2]) " " a[3] " " a[4] " " a[5] " " a[6])
    }
    # handle Job line, store line, zero variables
    /^Job/ {jobln=$0; tmsub=0; tmdis=0; next}
    # handle dispatched line, store, get dispatch timestamp, output all >= 1 hr
    tmsub != 0 {
        disln=$0
        tmdis=mktmstamp($1)
        if (tmdis-tmsub >= 3600)
            printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", jobln, subln, disln
    }
    # handle submit line, store line, get submit timestamp
    tmsub == 0 { subln=$0; tmsub=mktmstamp($1) }
' jobs
```

(**note:** you can create a self-contained script as well either by including the above in a shell script, or by creating an awk script -- but note with an awk script you will have to move the handling of obtaining the year into the `BEGIN {}` rule)

**Example Output**

```
Job <831953>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 31 09:37:28: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <medium>, CWD </sc
Wed Jul 31 11:47:05: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r05n42>, Allocated 40
Job <831955>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 30 09:37:29: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <medium>, CWD </sc
Wed Jul 31 09:47:07: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r03n10>, Allocated 40
Job <823777>, Job Name <3rd>, User <mse-jiangf>, Project <default>, Mail <ritaq
Wed Jul 31 09:55:14: Submitted from host <login04>, to Queue <medium>, CWD <$HO
Thu Aug  1 12:57:12: Dispatched 20 Task(s) on Host(s) <20*r03n09>, Allocated 20
```

Which are all the jobs where the dispatched time minus the submitted time is greater than or equal to one hour. Let me know if you have further questions.

---

**A Shorter Month Abrv. To Number**

Thanks to master [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton), the `month()` function can be re-written using `index` to eliminate the `gawk` `switch()` dependency as:

```
function month (m) {
    return (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNocDec",m)+2)/3
}
```

Or it can be included in the `mktmstamp()` function directly which shortens the overall script length significantly:

```
awk -F, -v y=$(date '+%Y') '
    # get current year above (no year info in data file)
    # function converts datespec (from submit/dispatch time) to timestamp
    # (e.g. "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS" to seconds since epoch)
    function mktmstamp (str) {
        sub(/:[^:]*$/,"",str)   # remove from final : to end
        gsub(/:/," ",str)       # replace : in H:M:S with space
        gsub(/[ ]0/," ",str)    # remove any leading zeros from H M S
        split (str, a, " ")     # split m d H M S into array
        # convert month abrv. to number
        mnth = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNocDec",a[2])+2)/3
        # return timestamp created from datespec
        return mktime(y " " mnth " " a[3] " " a[4] " " a[5] " " a[6])
    }
    # handle Job line, store line, zero variables
    /^Job/ {jobln=$0; tmsub=0; tmdis=0; next}
    # handle dispatched line, store, get dispatch timestamp, output all >= 1 hr
    tmsub != 0 {
        disln=$0
        tmdis=mktmstamp($1)
        if (tmdis-tmsub >= 3600)
            printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n", jobln, subln, disln
    }
    # handle submit line, store line, get submit timestamp
    tmsub == 0 { subln=$0; tmsub=mktmstamp($1) }
' file
```

Thanks to Ed -- again.

Comment: bravo for the explanations :O

Comment: Thanks, without them, `awk` is one of those things that can start looking real cryptic -- real quick...

Comment: wrt `mktime is a GNU awk extension (though most other awks provide it as well),` - Unless it's been added to mawk recently like gensub() was and I hadn't heard about it (which is possible), no other awks provide mktime. Also `switch` is gawk-only too. You can convert a 3-char month name to a month number with just `mthNr=(index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNocDec",mthName)+2)/3` though.

Comment: It says it has, "However, recent versions of `mawk` (see section Other Freely Available awk Implementations) also support these functions." [GNU awk - 9.1.5 Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html#Time-Functions) .. but I have to admit I haven't tried any version of `mawk` to make sure, so I have to take the GNU manual on faith. That `((index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNocDec",mthName)+2)/3` is a thing of beauty that I would not have dreamed up.

Comment: @EdMorton - while I have you, is there a better way to remove a leading zero from the log file month, day, hour, minute, second that would be preferred over `gsub(/[ ]0/," ",str)`?

Comment: Well, you don't need to put the  blank in a bracket expression since it's not a regexp metachar so you could write `gsub(/ 0/...` but you don't need to do that at all, there's no harm in just leaving the leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk :

```
awk '
function extract_date(line){
    split(line, date, /[: ]/)
    day = date[3] + 0
    if(day < 10){
        day = "0" day
    }
    return mktime("1996 " months[date[2]] " " day " " date[4] " " date[5] " " date[6])
}
BEGIN{
  months["Jan"] = "01"
  months["Feb"] = "02"
  months["Mar"] = "03"
  months["Apr"] = "04"
  months["May"] = "05"
  months["Jun"] = "06"
  months["Jul"] = "07"
  months["Aug"] = "08"
  months["Sep"] = "09"
  months["Oct"] = "10"
  months["Nov"] = "11"
  months["Dec"] = "12"
}
/Job Name/{job=$0}
/Submitted/{
    subm=$0;
}
/Dispatched/{
    start = extract_date(subm)
    end = extract_date($0)
    if(end-start < 0){
        end += 31536000
    }
    if(end-start > 3600){
        print job
        print subm
        print
    }
}' file
```

Awk :

```
awk -F": " '
function extract_date(str_date){
    cmd = "date -d \"" str_date "\" +%s"
    while ( ( cmd | getline result ) > 0 ) {
    }
    close(cmd);
    return result
}
/Job Name/{job=$0}
/Submitted/{
    subm=$0;
    start = extract_date($1)
}
/Dispatched/{
    end = extract_date($1)
    if(end-start < 0){
        end += 31536000
    }
    if(end-start > 3600){
        print job
        print subm
        print
    }
}' file
```

Return :

```
Job <831953>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 31 09:37:28: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <medium>, CWD </sc
Wed Jul 31 11:47:05: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r05n42>, Allocated 40
Job <831955>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 30 09:37:29: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <medium>, CWD </sc
Wed Jul 31 09:47:07: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r03n10>, Allocated 40
Job <823777>, Job Name <3rd>, User <mse-jiangf>, Project <default>, Mail <ritaq
Wed Jul 31 09:55:14: Submitted from host <login04>, to Queue <medium>, CWD <$HO
Thu Aug  1 12:57:12: Dispatched 20 Task(s) on Host(s) <20*r03n09>, Allocated 20
```

I handle the case where Dispatched time is not the same year by adding 31536000 seconds (1 year) when Dispatched time < Submitted time.

Answer (score 0):

I wish to improve on @Corentin Limier excellent `gawk` answer.

Avoid redundant string matching and calculations.

If data structure is consistent more efficient to use place/position calculations.

```
function extract_date(line){
    split(line, date, /[: ]/);
    day = date[3] + 0;
    if(day < 10){
        day = "0" day;
    }
    return mktime("1996 " months[date[2]] " " day " " date[4] " " date[5] " " date[6]);
}
BEGIN{
  months["Jan"] = "01";
  months["Feb"] = "02";
  months["Mar"] = "03";
  months["Apr"] = "04";
  months["May"] = "05";
  months["Jun"] = "06";
  months["Jul"] = "07";
  months["Aug"] = "08";
  months["Sep"] = "09";
  months["Oct"] = "10";
  months["Nov"] = "11";
  months["Dec"] = "12";
}
NR % 3 == 1 { # handel first line
    job = $0;
}
NR % 3 == 2 { # handel second line
    submitTime = extract_date(substr($0, 1, 19));
    submit = $0;
}
NR % 3 == 0 { # handel third line
    dispatchTime = extract_date(substr($0, 1, 19));
    timeDiff = dispatchTime - submitTime;
    if (timeDiff < 0) {timeDiff += 31536000};
    if (timeDiff <= 3600) {
        print job;
        print submit;
        print;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for time functions and gensub() and assuming all of your dates occur within the same, current year (we can massage the code based on whatever your real situation is if that's not true):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    year = strftime("%Y")
    minSecs = 60 * 60
}
idx = index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNocDec",$2) {
    prevSecs = secs
    secs = mktime(year " " (idx+2)/3 " " $3 " " gensub(/:/," ","g",$4))
}
{ rec = rec $0 ORS }
$5 == "Dispatched" {
    if ( (secs - prevSecs) >= minSecs ) {
        printf "%s", rec
    }
    rec = ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Job <831953>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 31 09:37:28: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <medium>, CWD </sc
Wed Jul 31 11:47:05: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r05n42>, Allocated 40
Job <831955>, Job Name <phys>, User <phy-zhangz>, Project <default>, Command <#
Wed Jul 30 09:37:29: Submitted from host <login02>, to Queue <medium>, CWD </sc
Wed Jul 31 09:47:07: Dispatched 40 Task(s) on Host(s) <40*r03n10>, Allocated 40
Job <823777>, Job Name <3rd>, User <mse-jiangf>, Project <default>, Mail <ritaq
Wed Jul 31 09:55:14: Submitted from host <login04>, to Queue <medium>, CWD <$HO
Thu Aug  1 12:57:12: Dispatched 20 Task(s) on Host(s) <20*r03n09>, Allocated 20
```